# Is the following possible in SQL query

Tags: mysql

Is the following possible, i been racking my brain to think of a solution.

I have an sql table, very simple table, few text columns and two int columns.

What i want to ideally do is allow user to add a row, but just the text columns and have the sql automatically put the numbers in the integer columns.

Ideally id like these numbers to random but not already exsist (so every row has a unique number) in the column. Also 10 digits long (but think that might be pushing it).

Is there anyway i can achieve this within the query itself?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sure - you pass the string as parameters to the Insert statement and the values as well - after you computed them. you can use SQL fucntion to generate the random number, or use the code you're calling from to generate them.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate unique int numbers for a row with setting it AUTO_INCREMENT. However if you want something like a random hash, you need to do it in your backend. (or in a stored procedure)

Just a thought: if you generate long enough random strings you don't need to worry about having duplication usually. So it's safe to generate a random string, try to insert it and repeat until you get a duplicate entry error. Won't happen most of the time so it might be quicker than checking it first with a select.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a random number using MySQL. This will generate a random number between 0 and 10.000:

```
FLOOR(RAND() * 10001)
```

If you really want the numbers to always be 10 digits long you can generate a number between 1.000.000.000 and 9.999.999.999 like this:

```
FLOOR(RAND() * 9000000000) + 1000000000
```

The chance of the number not being unique is ~0.0000000001% and rising as you insert new rows. For a 0% chance of collision I'd suggest doing this the right way and handling this in code and not the database.

The random function explained:

What is happening is `RAND()` is generating a random decimal number between 0 and 1 (never actually 1). Then we multiply that number by the maximum number that we wish to produce plus 1. We add 1 because the biggest number produced for a set maximum number of 10 will be 9,XXXX and never actually 10 or above (remember I said that `RAND()` never generates 1), so we add plus one to produce the possibility of 10,XXXX which we later floor using `FLOOR()` to produce 10. In this case though we don't add 1 because 10.000.000.000 will become possible and it breaches our 10 digit boundary. Then we add the minimum number which we want produced (+ 1.000.000.000 in this case) while subtracting the same from the number we entered before (the maximum number).